# Can I dynamically import TypeScript modules in Node.js/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a Node.js server built with Express.js and coded in TypeScript. Here's a snippet of the get call for my server:

server.ts

```
private get(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction, objectName: string) {
    var DatabaseObject = require("./models/" + objectName + ".js")(this.orm, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    var Transform = require("./routes/" + objectName + ".js");
    var transform = new Transform();

    // ...

    console.log(req.query["columns"]);
    console.log(transform.columnWhitelist);
    console.log(transform);

    // ...

    if (transform.columnWhitelist) {
        console.log("Column Whitelist Exists.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

It dynamically loads the Sequelize module for the database object being requested in the URL and then tries to load a TypeScript module with rules on what columns can be selected, which columns can be queried on, etc. Here's the beginning of my ruleset class:

account.ts

```
export default class Transform {
    static columnWhitelist : Object = {"id": "id", "name": "name", "parentAccountId":"parentAccountId", "masterAccountId":"masterAccountId"};

    constructor() { }
}
```

However, running my application, I get:

```
id,name,parentAccountId
undefined
{ default: 
   { [Function: Transform]
     columnWhitelist: 
      { id: 'id',
        name: 'name',
        parentAccountId: 'parentAccountId',
        masterAccountId: 'masterAccountId' } } }
```

Making the call transform.columnWhitelist, I get undefined, despite seeing it in the generated JavaScript file as well. I've also tried just:

```
    var transform = require("./routes/" + objectName + ".js");
```

Or:

```
    var transform = require("./routes/" + objectName + ".js")();
```

But neither of these work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have commonjs as a module in your tsconfig.json and Transform class exported as default you should probably import it as

```
 var transform = require("./routes/" + objectName + ".js").default;
```

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot! At one point I did try `var Transform = require("./routes/" + objectName + ".js"); var transform = Transform.Transform;` or something like that but I must've typed something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use

```
var transform = require("./routes/" + objectName + ".js").default;
```

You can export your class by doing

```
class Transform {
     static columnWhitelist: Object = {"id": "id", "name": "name", "parentAccountId": "parentAccountId", "masterAccountId": "masterAccountId"};

     constructor () {}
}

export = Transform;
```

After you can do again as before:

```
var transform = require ("./ routes /" + objectName + ".js");
```

Comment: Is `export = Transform;` TypeScript-specific syntax versus the `module.exports = ...` of JavaScript, or another way of writing the latter?

Comment: **export =** is used to give typescript the **export default** behavior. In addition it works with interfaces, functions, enums etc ...

You can find out more by reading the documentation
[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) (you can do a search with export =)

if you want to keep typing, you can add: var transform: typeof Transform = require("./routes/" +objectName+ ".js");